# TypedQuery<Boolean> returns BigDecimal

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, jpql

I am trying to write a JPQL query which returns a `boolean`, but even if I specify the result class as `Boolean.class` my query is still returning an object of type `BigDecimal`.

```
Query q = em.createQuery(
    "SELECT CASE WHEN ( count(e) > 0 ) THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE END"                        
                    + "FROM MyEntity e "
                    // + WHERE CLause etc...
                    , Boolean.class);   
    // Setting query-Params etc.. 

    // Fails, because BigDecimal cannot be converted to Boolean
    // return q.getSingleResult();

   // Workaorund:
   BigDecimal res = (BigDecimal) q.getSingleResult();        
   return res.intValue() > 0;
```

As you can see I have a simple workaround, but I'd like to know, if there is a problem in my Query or why do I get a BigDecimal instead of a Boolean?

My JPA Provider is EclipseLink (2.6.0) and I am using Oracle 11g

So is there (a) a problem with the Query above? or (b) is this behaviour JPA specific or (c) is it related to EclipseLink or (d) is it because Oracle does not support Boolean?

---

**EDIT** I created a ticket for this bug, you will find it here:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=482885

Comment: I vote for (d), but it is strange.

Comment: I vote for (c), because the JPA provider should handle DB "problems" and not expose them to the user

Comment: Tried that same query with DataNucleus and same RDBMS, returns a Boolean, as it should. Raise a bug on your JPA provider

Comment: I guess it is a combination of 'c' and 'd' as Oracle doesn't understand true or false.  Show the SQL (with parameters) that is generated and file a bug with EclipseLink to have it workaround the issue as it could remember what it uses for true/false and translate the values back for you.

Comment: I created a ticket for this issue. If someone is interested in it, you will find the ticket here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=482885